# Connecting to Active Directory which is present in Virtual Machine (Azure)

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-machine

We are having a situation where we need to connect to Active Directory that is setup in a Virtual Machine (in Azure Environment) from a Desktop Application / Windows Service (C#). 
As I am new to AD, need to know the setp-by-step procedure which I need to follow for:

1. Connecting to Active Directory (hosted in Virtual Machine) from my desktop app/ Windows service (locally).
2. Get almost all the information from Active Directory (Users, Groups etc...)
3. Able to create / update / delete information (Users / Groups) from my app to Active Directory (hosted in VM).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2015/01/21/install-a-new-active-directory-forest-on-an-azure-virtual-network.aspx and here http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2013/01/17/step-by-step-building-a-windows-server-2012-active-directory-forest-in-the-cloud-with-windows-azure.aspx are some instructions to get you started creating the Active Directory forest in the cloud.

Once AD is installed you need to connect to it from inside your computer/organization. Depending on your needs, there are several ways (point-to-site, site-to-site and ExpressRoute) you can connect to a virtual network in Azure.

E.g. see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-site-to-site-create/ for instructions on how to set up a site-to-site VPN to connect your organization desktop machines to the forest.

Now you should be able to join your desktop machines to the AD forest.

After this you should be able to start using the newly created AD in your on-prem network. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C for starts how to do the most common operations.

Comment: Hello Kim...Thanks for the swift response. As you have mentioned, we have VM ready with active directory. However we are not able to connect to VM's active directory from local system via Windows Service (C#). I would like to know whether is there any configurations which i have missed or is there any port i need to configure. I would like to know the exact connection string which i need to provide for connecting to Active Directory from my Windows Service (C#).

Comment: Have you verified that it is working in the cloud first? E.g. write some short program and try it out on the VM in question.

If this works, try to create a VPN to your computer. If you only got one computer you can create a point-to-site VPN. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-point-to-site-create/ how to do it.

Comment: We configured the ports and provided access to our system IP in VM. Now we are able to connect to Active Directory from our application. Thanks a lot!! Kim.